# How to remove page after back operation?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In my app, I load some data, use timers etc.. but I realized that when the user presses `Back` button or myself do it:

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

timers of the page are still working. I won't return back to this page by:

```
NavigationService.GoForward();
```

and will just navigate to it by

```
NavigationService.Navigate("...");
```

So leaving these timers, and other loaded data doesn't look good.

How can I remove/dispose these pages and their data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop all of your operations within the `OnNavigatingFrom` Method

[MSDN OnNavigatingFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Something like this

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    //Stop all of your timers 

    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);

}
```

Comment: thanks @AMR. that is fine. so there is not something like dispose for objects?

Comment: If you dispose of the objects then it will break when you navigate back to the page. Give it a shot. There should be a dispose on each timer. Please don't forget to upvote and select as the answer if this worked for you.